# How do other modules update elements using AJAX callbacks?

Tags: 7, forms, ajax

I have a block, of which I want to update the contents via AJAX. So the block is:

```
$block['subject'] = t('My Block');
$block['content'] = '<div id="block_wrapper"></div>';
```

And the form element AJAX part:

```
$form['select_element']['#ajax'] = array(
  'callback' => 'ajax_callback',
  'wrapper' => 'block_wrapper',
  'method' => 'replace',
);
```

The callback:

```
function ajax_callback($form, $form_state) {
  return views_embed_view('view_name', 'default', $form_state['values']['select_element']);
}
```

However when I change the form element the whole block content is replaced and the wrapper is replaced by a empty div, so subsequent alterations of the select element fail to update the block.

The [wrapper documentation](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7#ajax_wrapper) explains the entire div is replaced, not just it contents. But many modules (like for example Views) have dynamically updating form elements where changing a select element toggles other parts of a form, which keeps working no matter how often you change it. Do they insert the wrapper div again in the response? And how should I alter the response of views_embed_view to put the contents in a wrapper div?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks @Tasneem for directing me. I did it as follows:

```
function hook_form() {
  $form['select_element'] = array(
    '#type' => 'select',
    '#options' => $options,
    '#default_value' => $default,
    '#ajax' => array(
      'callback' => 'ajax_callback',
      'wrapper' => 'block_wrapper',
      'method' => 'replace',
    ),
  );

  $form['block_wrapper'] = array(
    '#type' => 'item',
    '#title' => t('Contents'),
    '#id' => 'block_wrapper',
    '#markup' => views_embed_view(...),
  );

  return $form;
}


function ajax_callback($form, $form_state) {
  $form['block_wrapper'] = array(
    '#type' => 'item',
    '#title' => t('Contents'),
    '#id' => 'block_wrapper',
    '#markup' => views_embed_view(...),
  );

  // Returning the entire $form here made the select element appear twice, so only return the wrapper element.
  return $form['block_wrapper'];
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I think you must to create block_wrapper in the $form before ajax as a container :

```
$form['select_element']['block_wrapper'] = array(
'#type' => 'container',
'#id' => 'block_wrapper',
'#attributes' => array(
  'class' => array('myclass')
  ),
);
```

to make ajax wrapper found it.

Comment: The problem is that the div with the id is replaced by the AJAX call, so no matter in what way I add it, it will be replaced.

Comment: try to put view directily in the form in callback funtion not return .. or remove method => 'replace'